# Check if all elements of one array is in another array

Tags: python, list

I have these two arrays:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

And:

```
B = [4,5,6,7]
```

Is there a way to check if B is a sublist in A with the same exact order of items?

Comment: list order is to be preserved, right?

Comment: The order of the elements of B is the same as the part that includes it in A, if is that your question.

Comment: I believe he's asking does it matter what order the elements are in? For example...

Would B=[4,6,5,7] be just as good, or does order matter?

Comment: The order of the elements in A and B matters. Is like see if B is a cut of the list A.

Comment: Any ideas if I wanna get the rest array, like C = A - B = [1,2,3,8,9,0]？

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] 

B = [4,5,6,7]
C = [7,8,9,0]
D = [4,6,7,5]

def is_slice_in_list(s,l):
    len_s = len(s) #so we don't recompute length of s on every iteration
    return any(s == l[i:len_s+i] for i in xrange(len(l) - len_s+1))
```

Result:

```
>>> is_slice_in_list(B,A)
True
>>> is_slice_in_list(C,A)
True
>>> is_slice_in_list(D,A)
False
```

Answer (score 60):

[issubset](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) should help you

```
set(B).issubset(set(A))
```

e.g.:

```
>>> A= [1,2,3,4]
>>> B= [2,3]
>>> set(B).issubset(set(A))
True
```

edit: **wrong**, this solution does not imply the order of the elements!

Comment: +1 as I found this helpful and also appreciate the note on how it didn't quite answer the OP but was left here for those who might stumble upon it.  Thanks.

Comment: also note that set([]).issubset(set([1,2,3])) evaluates to True

Answer (score 4):

Using slicing:

```
for i in range(len(A) - len(B)):
    if A[i:i+len(B)] == B:
        return True
return False
```

Something like that will work if your A is larger than B.

Comment: That would work even if A is smaller than B, the only case you should care of is equal lengths. That note shows that you probably should use `range(len(A)-len(B)+1)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `index` to identify the starting point.  With this small example, it is faster than the iterative solutions:

```
def foo(A,B):
    n=-1
    while True:
        try:
            n = A.index(B[0],n+1)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        if A[n:n+len(B)]==B:
            return True
```

Times with this are fairly constant regardless of `B` (long, short, present or not).  Times for the iterative solutions vary with where `B` starts.

To make this more robust I've tested against

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

which is longer, and repeats values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.linalg.hankel` to create all the sub-arrays in one line and then check if your array is in there. A quick example is as follows:

```
from scipy import linalg

A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] 

B = [4,5,6,7]

hankel_mat = linalg.hankel(A, A[::-1][:len(B)])[:-1*len(B)+1]  # Creating a matrix with a shift of 1 between rows, with len(B) columns

B in hankel_mat  # Should return True if B exists in the same order inside A
```

This will not work if B is longer than A, but in that case I believe there is no point in checking :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import array

def Check_array(c):
    count = 0
    count2 = 0  

    a = array.array('i',[4, 11, 20, -4, -3, 11, 3, 0, 50]);
    b = array.array('i', [20, -3, 0]);
    
    for i in range(0,len(b)):
        
        for j in range(count2,len(a)):
            if a[j]==b[i]:
                    count = count + 1
                    count2 = j
                    break           
    if count == len(b): 
        return bool (True);
    else:
        return bool (False);

res = Check_array(8)
print(res)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

By subverting your `list` to `string`, you can easily verify if the string "4567" is in the string "1234567890".

```py
stringA = ''.join([str(_) for _ in A])
stringB = ''.join([str(_) for _ in B])

stringB in stringA 
>>> True
```

Dressed as a one line (cause is cooler)

```py
isBinA = ''.join([str(_) for _ in B]) in ''.join([str(_) for _ in A])
isBinA 
>>> True
```

Comment: Does not work for some inputs : `A = [45]` and `B = [4,5]` for example.

Answer (score -4):

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
B = [4,5,6,7]

(A and B) == B

True
```