# Doesnt compare list's correctly

Tags: python, list, string-comparison, whitelist

```
def split(word):
    x = list(word)
    return x



whitelist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P']




word = input('Password ')
split(word)
x = split(word)

if x not in whitelist:
    print('Incorrect letters')
else: 
    print('Correct ')
```

When i enter FECHCH for eks. , 'if' keeps giving me communicate - inncorrect letters .
I need python3 to understand, that letters FECHCH are in whitelist.

Comment: You want an intersection. `in` does not check if two lists overlap; only if the list contains a single element. `whitelist` does not contain the entirety of `x` as an element, so the check is false.

Comment: You can use `set()` instead of a list and use `issubset()` to check if all elements are being contained in `whitelist`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789412/check-if-all-elements-of-one-array-is-in-another-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter letters one by one

```
def split(word):
    x = list(word)
    return x

whitelist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P']

word = input('Password ')
split(word)
x = split(word)
print(x)

#Password FECHCH
['F', 'E', 'C', 'H', 'C', 'H']
```

so you are comparing:

```
['F', 'E', 'C', 'H', 'C', 'H'] in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P']
```

which is `False`

as mentioned in comments, you can use a `set()` to remove duplicates and check subsets.

```
word = input('Password ')
split(word)
x = split(word)

if set(x).issubset(whitelist):
    print('Correct ')
    
else: 
    print('Incorrect letters')
```

Answer (score 0):

No special split function is required. You could simply use (assuming you accept lower case letters to be converted else omit upper():

```
whitelist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P']

word = input('Password ')

# to report on each character   

for ch in word.upper():
    if ch not in whitelist:
        print('Incorrect letter', ch)
    else: 
        print('Correct letter', ch)

# or to check the whole word

for ch in word.upper():
    if ch not in whitelist:
        val = 'Incorrect letters'
        break
else:
    val = 'correct letters'
print(val)
```